# MSAccess Merging 2 tables into 1 with no blanks

Tags: database, ms-access, merge, ms-access-2013

I have a bit of a hard question. I have 2 tables in my database, the data is from Laptops assigned to Students in certain programs:

Table 1 has the following info: Model, SiteID, SiteName, ServiceTag, AssetTag, Floor, Room, FirstName, LastName, STUDENTID, Grade

Table 2 has the following info: SiteID, SiteName, LastName, FirstName, Grade, STUDENTID

Table 1 has the data from Last Year's roster, with the student and their assigned computer. Table 2 has the new roster of students that are in the program. Some of the students on Table 2 Match the ones on Table 1 (the students that are still in the program) but there are some that don't.

I need to do the following: Grab all the students on Table 2 and assign them a Machine that is already at the said SiteID (school where the machine is at), while taking into consideration that some students are still in the program and they are getting their same machine assigned to them and leave blanks where i need to deploy new machines for extra students.

I was trying to insert images here to show an example but its not letting me. If you can help me I will gladly email you a basic example with data on it.

Edit 1:
So far I was able to get a query to give me back the students that are still in the program and give them their originally assigned machine, but the other machines have no assigned students to them, I am trying to figure out how fill in the data of the other machines with the names of new students. Bare in mind that there are multiple schools im dealing with and the machines cannot be moved from one school to another and if there are more students in the new roster vs before then I will have to leave those students with no machine assigned to them and deploy new systems.

Edit 2:
Below is a CSV version of the Tables and the results I am trying to get.

```
TABLE 1
MODEL,SITE_ID,SITENAME,SERVICETAG,ASSETTAG,FLOOR,ROOM,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,STUDENTID,GRADE
6420,123,MY SCHOOL,1234GM1,AT0012345,1,102,PETER,PEREZ,100123456,1
6420,123,MY SCHOOL,5678GM1,AT0012346,1,102,PAUL,ANDREWS,100123457,1
6420,123,MY SCHOOL,1234FH1,AT0012347,1,102,JOHN,BERRONDO,100123458,3
6420,123,MY SCHOOL,5678FH1,AT0012348,1,102,ANDREW,JONES,100123459,3
6420,123,MY SCHOOL,12344K1,AT0012349,1,102,JONATHAN,DOE,100123460,4

TABLE 2
SITEID,SITENAME,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,STUDENTID,GRADE
123,MY SCHOOL,PAUL,ANDREWS,100123457,2
123,MY SCHOOL,JOHN,BERRONDO,100123458,4
123,MY SCHOOL,ANGEL,YOUNG,100123470,1
123,MY SCHOOL,TANIA,MATTHEWS,100123471,1
123,MY SCHOOL,GEORGE,PEREZ,100123472,2
123,MY SCHOOL,WALTER,DOE,100123473,2
123,MY SCHOOL,MATTHEW,PETERS,100123474,3

RESULTING TABLE
SITE ID,SITENAME,SERVICETAG,ASSETTAG,FIRSTNAME1,LASTNAME2,STUDENTID,GRADE
123,MY SCHOOL,5678GM1,AT0012346,PAUL,ANDREWS,100123457,2
123,MY SCHOOL,1234FH1,AT0012347,JOHN,BERRONDO,100123458,4
123,MY SCHOOL,1234GM1,AT0012345,ANGEL,YOUNG,100123470,1
123,MY SCHOOL,5678FH1,AT0012348,TANIA,MATTHEWS,100123471,1
123,MY SCHOOL,12344K1,AT0012349,GEORGE,PEREZ,100123472,2
123,MY SCHOOL,,,WALTER,DOE,100123473,2
123,MY SCHOOL,,,MATTHEW,PETERS,100123474,3
```

I have tried the following SQL queries:

```
SELECT table2.SITEID, table2.SITENAME, table2.LASTNAME, table2.FIRSTNAME, table2.GRADE, table2.STUDENTID, table1.SERVICETAG, table1.ASSETTAG, 
FROM 
table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.STUDENTID=table1.STUDENTID;
```

This query is giving me the full list of students on the roster, and for those that match with the old data they retain their machine, the rest are left blank.

```
SELECT table1.[SITEID], table1.[SITENAME], table1.[SERVICETAG], table1.[ASSETTAG]
FROM table1 LEFT JOIN [query 1] ON table1.[SERVICETAG] = [query 1].[SERVICETAG]
WHERE ((([query 1].[SERVICETAG]) Is Null));
```

this is giving me the machines that are not assigned yet to any student from the new roster.

```
SELECT table2.SITEID, table2.SITENAME, table2.LASTNAME, table2.FIRSTNAME, table2.GRADE, table2.STUDENTID
FROM table2 LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.STUDENTID= table1.STUDENTID
WHERE (((table1.STUDENTID) Is Null))
ORDER BY table2.SITEID;
```

This one is giving me the Students that don't have a matching computer (in other words the students that need a machine assigned to them)

As you can see I have all the in between and it would be nice if I could finally join this data and get the result shown on the CSV result demo.

UPDATE 3:
I have decided to take it the excel way for now, it's become half automatic and half manual. Im using a VLOOKUP system that is kind off giving me what I need but I have to be careful on my data.

I will keep updating as I get closer.

Comment: Instead of just querying, couldn't you just use a Make Table to make a new table that doesn't contain existing students?

Comment: The problem is that i need to be able to assign the machines already existing in a school to the new roster of students, and take into account that some students are coming back this year from previous roster.

Comment: So are you just trying to avoid doing all of this manually then?  Because I'm pretty sure you can just Make a table queried against next year's list that contains reoccurring students.  Then make another table where reoccurring students don't appear.  Merge those two after.  That way you can keep your old tables in case you need to look up old data, and make a new one each year for each school.

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with UNION queries?  That may be the easiest path for you.  This isn't a real answer, but I can't comment yet so this is what I have.  Essentially you create two queries with (preferably) the same number of columns of like data, but each can have distinct criteria; Such as 
Select StudentID, AssetTag from Table1 Inner Join Table2 On Table1.StudentID = Table2.StudentID
UNION
Select Table2.StudentID, Table1.AssetTag From Table2 Left Join Table1 On Table2.StudentID = Table1.StudentID Where Table1.StudentID is null

Not sure that's 100% accurate, but hopefully you get the idea.  Create two queries, match the columns, and join them in SQL view with the word 'UNION'

Here is the Union from the datastructure you provided:

SELECT tble1.Model, tble1.Site_ID, tble1.SiteName, tble1.ServiceTag, tble1.AssetTag, tble1.Floor, tble1.Room, tble1.FirstName, tble1.LastName, tble1.StudentID, tble1.Grade
FROM tble1 INNER JOIN tble2 ON tble1.StudentID = tble2.StudentID;
UNION
SELECT tble1.Model, tble1.Site_ID, tble1.SiteName, tble1.ServiceTag, tble1.AssetTag, tble1.Floor, tble1.Room, tble2.FirstName, tble2.LastName, tble2.StudentID, tble2.Grade
FROM tble1 RIGHT JOIN tble2 ON tble1.StudentID = tble2.StudentID
WHERE (((tble1.StudentID) Is Null));

To get close I fear you'll need manual input.  Sorry.

Comment: I tried a UNION but it keeps giving me an error on JOIN command.

Comment: Can you post the SQL?  That will help get the details correct.

Comment: Hmmm, Non-normalized data is problematic for this type of thing.  The issue is you have no way (that I can see anyway) of matching the incoming students to 'unassigned' computers.  Nothing links them, and without that link you have Cartesian joins, which while useful in certain specifications, would be bad here.  You could do it with VBA, writing a loop statement to iterate through the available assets, but I suspect that's not what you wanted.  I'll append my 'answer' above with the Union I was talking about, but it still requires manual update of asset data.